# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Replace single character on select

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, replace, subquery

How do I replace a character with multiple rows using update

```
UPDATE tbl_FMaster
SET PHOTO = (
        SELECT Replace(PHOTO, 'D:\', ' A : \ ') PHOTO
        FROM tbl_FMaster
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a subquery at all assuming you just want to run the `REPLACE` statement on the `photo` value in each row.

```
UPDATE tbl_FMaster
   SET photo = REPLACE( photo, 'D:\', 'A:\' );
```